# Sheevuh mayoys (700) mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

B"H

Hi

Every number has some significance in the Torah, so what then is special about the number 700 (represented by final noon according to one gematria system)?

Blessings and success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among all this people there were **seven hundred chosen men** lefthanded; every one could sling stones at a hair, and not miss. [Judges 20:16]

Answer (score 1):

When Rabbi Elazar ben Azarya took over from Rabban Gamliel, he opened the doors of the study hall to all who sought to learn Torah.  **Seven hundred benches** were added to the study hall. [Berakhot 28a]

Answer (score 1):

The king of Moab led an attempt of **seven hundred swordsmen** to break a way through to the king of Edom.  They failed. [2 Kings 3:26]

Answer (score 1):

Shlomo HaMelech had 700 royal wives (and 300 concubines)

[Malachim I 11:3](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.11.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi):

> וַיְהִי־ל֣וֹ **נָשִׁ֗ים שָׂרוֹת֙ שְׁבַ֣ע מֵא֔וֹת** וּפִֽלַגְשִׁ֖ים שְׁלֹ֣שׁ מֵא֑וֹת וַיַּטּ֥וּ נָשָׁ֖יו אֶת־לִבּֽוֹ׃
>
> He had **seven hundred royal wives** and three hundred concubines; and his wives turned his heart away.

Answer (score 1):

In the third month of the 15th year of Asa, King of Yehuda's reign a number of sacrifices were brought.

It writes in [Divrei HaYamim II 15:11](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.15.11?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi):

> וַיִּזְבְּח֤וּ לַה' בַּיּ֣וֹם הַה֔וּא מִן־הַשָּׁלָ֖ל הֵבִ֑יאוּ **בָּקָר֙ שְׁבַ֣ע מֵא֔וֹת** וְצֹ֖אן שִׁבְעַ֥ת אֲלָפִֽים׃
>
> They brought sacrifices to the LORD on that day; they brought **700 oxen** and 7,000 sheep of the spoil.

Answer (score 1):

[Shmuel II 10:18](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.10.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi):

> וַיָּ֣נָס אֲרָם֮ מִפְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵל֒ **וַיַּהֲרֹ֨ג דָּוִ֜ד מֵאֲרָ֗ם שְׁבַ֤ע מֵאוֹת֙ רֶ֔כֶב** וְאַרְבָּעִ֥ים אֶ֖לֶף פָּרָשִׁ֑ים וְאֵ֨ת שׁוֹבַ֧ךְ שַׂר־צְבָא֛וֹ הִכָּ֖ה וַיָּ֥מָת שָֽׁם׃
>
> And the Arameans fled because of Israel. **David killed 700 Aramean charioteers** and 40,000 horsemen; he also struck down Shobach, Hadad-ezer’s army commander, who died there.

Answer (score 1):

When Joshua took over the leadership after Moses' death, 700 halachic uncertainties arose. (Temura 16a)

> אמר רב יהודה אמר רב בשעה שנפטר משה רבינו לגן עדן אמר לו ליהושע שאל
> ממני כל ספיקות שיש לך אמר לו רבי כלום הנחתיך שעה אחת והלכתי למקום אחר
> לא כך כתבת בי (שמות לג, יא) ומשרתו יהושע בן נון נער לא ימיש מתוך האהל
> מיד תשש כחו של יהושע ונשתכחו ממנו שלש מאות הלכות ונולדו לו שבע מאות
> ספיקות ועמדו כל ישראל להרגו

Answer (score 1):

As a result of Isiah's curse, 700 orders of Mishnah were lost, leaving only the [six we have today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah). (Chagiga 14a)

> **שְׁמוֹנֶה עֶשְׂרֵה קְלָלוֹת מַאי נִינְהוּ** דִּכְתִיב כִּי הִנֵּה
> הָאָדוֹן ה׳ צְבָאוֹת **מֵסִיר מִירוּשָׁלִַם וּמִיהוּדָה מַשְׁעֵן
> וּמַשְׁעֵנָה**...
>
> **מַשְׁעֵנָה אֵלּוּ בַּעְלֵי מִשְׁנָה** כְּגוֹן רַבִּי יְהוּדָה
> בֶּן תֵּימָא וַחֲבֵירָיו פְּלִיגִי בַּהּ רַב פָּפָּא וְרַבָּנַן חַד
> אָמַר שֵׁשׁ מֵאוֹת סִדְרֵי מִשְׁנָה **וְחַד אָמַר שְׁבַע מֵאוֹת סִדְרֵי
> מִשְׁנָה**